# SharePoint add-only Item Permission

Tags: list, list-view, item-level-permissions

I am looking for a way to let users create items in a list with the following Criteria:

1. User can only add Items.
2. No view access to the list items including created items by the
   user.

I've tried the following steps:

1. SharePoint Workflows and Microsoft flows.

   -Issue: It is slow to set item permission and it causes a security risk for the business. Also, the Risk of workflow failure.
2. Site Custom Permission does not allow the creation of add-only permission.
3. Read items that were created by the user from advanced Sharepoint list settings.

To Sum up: I would like to create a form that user can submit queries. After submission, depending on the business flow a series of processes (Sending emails, Approval Tasks, etc.) require to start. The solution is fully implemented but I am looking to find a way to fix the item permission security issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Azure function that has app-only permissions to SharePoint site and list.

1. Register an App in Azure for accessing SharePoint. Grant permissions for it using Azure AD portal or using SharePoint Add-in model (it is still supported and allows you to have more granular permissions)
2. Create Azure function, secure it with Azure AD that creates list items in list using registered App with App-only permissions. Secure you Azure function with Azure AD. This way you can save authenticated user information in separate user field in your list.
3. Create a form (possible with SPFx) that call your Azure Function.

Using this approach user will not need any direct permissions to you list.

Comment: Thank you! @CM4D
I was hoping for a simpler solution but I can see the potential and scalability of it.